# Why does this query use the primary key?

Tags: mysql, indexing

These are WordPress post tables, but that part shouldn't matter. I've removed a few fields from the SELECT part to make the question more simple.

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title
FROM    wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)
WHERE   wp_posts.post_type = 'series'
AND     wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
LIMIT 100, 100;
```

`EXPLAIN` output

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys       key     key_len ref             rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  wp_posts    index   type_status_date    PRIMARY 8       NULL             29     Using where
1   SIMPLE  wp_postmeta ref     post_id             post_id 8       db.wp_posts.ID   13     Using index
```

Not that I'm complaining, but I'm wondering why the primary key was used when all the `WHERE`s are not using it. This query runs instantly even with 1.5 rows in the `wp_postmeta` table. What's also interesting is that as soon as I add an order that is not the ID, like `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC` it takes 3 seconds to run.

So what causes the primary key to be used in the query above?

Comment: It's the `GROUP BY` (and probably the `JOIN` as well). `WHERE`s aren't the only thing that matter.

Comment: Of course, don't know why I didn't see that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will refrain from yet again spouting choice words about the WP.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.  In the absence of that info, I will guess that this is missing, but needed:

```
INDEX(post_type, post_status, ID)
```

The first two columns in that 'composite' index can be in either order.

*I've removed a few fields from the SELECT part to make the question more simple.* -- You have invalidated your question!  Now `LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID)` is totally useless and should be removed.